# Results from selections in nested st_aggrid showing all items, not only the selected ones

Tags: ag-grid, resultset, streamlit, multipleselection

Started with the example from [here](https://github.com/PablocFonseca/streamlit-aggrid/blob/main/examples/nested_grids.py)

Both the main grid, and the nested grid show up and allow selections.

However the `st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows']` doesn't show the selections from the nested grid properly.

- ***If you don't check the "Instrument_name" checkbox, then the response is nothing at all (regardless as to whether you check anything in the subgrid or not.)***
- ***If you DO check the "Instrument_name" checkbox, it shows everything from the subgrid (whether checked or not.)***

  ```
  gridOptions = {
    # enable Master / Detail
    "masterDetail": True,
    "rowSelection": "multiple",
    "pagination": st.session_state["enable_pagination"],
    "paginationAutoPageSize": st.session_state["paginationAutoSize"],
    "groupSelectsChildren":st.session_state["groupSelectsChildren"], 
    "groupSelectsFiltered":st.session_state["groupSelectsFiltered"],

    # the first Column is configured to use agGroupCellRenderer
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "field": "instrument_name",
            "cellRenderer": "agGroupCellRenderer",
            "checkboxSelection": True,
        },
    ],
    "defaultColDef": {
        # "flex": 1,
    },
    # provide Detail Cell Renderer Params
    "detailCellRendererParams": {
        # provide the Grid Options to use on the Detail Grid
        "detailGridOptions": {
            "rowSelection": "multiple",
            "suppressRowClickSelection": True,
            "enableRangeSelection": True,
            "pagination": st.session_state["enable_pagination"],
            "paginationAutoPageSize": st.session_state["paginationAutoSize"],
            "groupSelectsChildren":st.session_state["groupSelectsChildren"], 
            "groupSelectsFiltered":st.session_state["groupSelectsFiltered"],
            "columnDefs": [
                        {"field": "sample_name", "checkboxSelection": True},
                        {"field": "sample_type"},
                        {"field": "sample_orderno"},
                        {"field": "sample_amount"},
                        {"field": "injection_acquireddate"},
                        {"field": "injection_acquiredby"},
                        {"field": "injection_acqmethodversion"},
                        {"field": "injection_acquisitionorderno"},
                        {"field": "injection_volume"},
                        {"field": "injection_volumeunit"},
                        {"field": "injection_runtime"},
                        {"field": "injection_diagnosticdata"},
                        {"field": "injection_datafilename"},
                        {"field": "injection_datafiledirectory"},
                        {"field": "injection_lastmodifieddate"},
                        {"field": "injection_lastmodifiedby"},
                        {"field": "injection_damethodversion"},
                        {"field": "injection_orderno"},
                        {"field": "injection_manualmodification"},
                        {"field": "injection_noisetype"},
                        {"field": "injection_refinjectioninfo"},
                        {"field": "injection_dadilutionfactors"},
                        {"field": "injection_damultipliers"},
                        {"field": "injection_dainternalstandards"},
                        {"field": "injection_dacalibstandards"},
                        {"field": "injection_daruntypes"},
                        {"field": "injection_acqmethod_id"},
                        {"field": "injection_acqmethodname"},
                        {"field": "injection_damethod_id"},
                        {"field": "injection_damethodname"},
                        {"field": "injection_damethodquanttype"},
                        {"field": "resources"},
                        {"field": "instrument_id"},
                        {"field": "instrument_name"},
                        {"field": "instrument_technique"},
            ],
            "defaultColDef": {
                "sortable": True,
                # "flex": 1, # This sets the columns to fit to the window (bad)
            },
        },
        "getDetailRowData": JsCode(
            """function (params) {
                console.log(params);
                params.successCallback(JSON.parse(params.data.instrumentData));
    }"""
       ).js_code,
    },
  }
  st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"] = AgGrid(
    st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"],
    gridOptions=gridOptions,
    # height=500,
    height=st.session_state["grid_height"],    
    allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
    enable_enterprise_modules=True,
    # update_mode=GridUpdateMode.SELECTION_CHANGED,
    data_return_mode=st.session_state["return_mode_value"], 
    update_mode="manual",    
    # update_mode=st.session_state["update_mode_value"],    
    # editable=True
  )

  # Discover any data selected from grid
  #===============================================================================
  # Injections from instruments grid
  #===============================================================================
  if st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'] != []:
    import pickle
    pickle.dump(st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'], open("/home/mikes/shares/Downloads/allselected.pickle", "wb"))
    _tmp = st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows']
    st.write("""st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'] = Type:{}, len:{}""".format(type(_tmp), len(_tmp)))

    # st.write(st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'])
    #=======================================================================
    # _selected_instruments = pd.DataFrame(st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'])["instrument_name"].to_list()
    # st.write(_selected_instruments)
    #=======================================================================
    _tmp = pd.DataFrame(st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'])
    st.header("----------")
    st.write("""pd.DataFrame(st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows']) ... """)
    st.dataframe(_tmp)

    _tmp = pd.DataFrame(st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'])["instrumentData"]#.to_list()[0]
    st.header("----------")
    st.write("""st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'])["instrumentData"] ...""")
    st.dataframe(_tmp)

    _tmp = pd.DataFrame(st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'])["instrumentData"].to_list()
    st.header("----------")
    st.write("len of list = {} elements".format(len(_tmp)))
    st.write("""st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'])["instrumentData"].to_list() ...""")
    st.write(_tmp)

    _tmp = pd.DataFrame(st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'])["instrumentData"].to_list()[0]
    st.header("----------")
    st.write("""Taking the first element gives a string of a list of dictionaries...""")
    st.write("""st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'])["instrumentData"].to_list()[0] ...""")
    st.write("type = {}".format(type(_tmp)))
    st.write(_tmp)

    st.header("----------")
    st.header("""**The list shows all 9 items from the sub-grid, even though not all 9 were selected...**""")
    st.markdown("""Converting it back to a list with ast. **The list shows all 9 items from the sub-grid, even though not all 9 were selected...**""")
    _tmp = ast.literal_eval(_tmp)
    st.write("type = {}".format(type(_tmp)))
    st.write("len of list = {} elements".format(len(_tmp)))
    st.write(_tmp)
  ```

---

**So when the selections are like this...**

[image: Selected items]

**The responses appear as (snipped for brevity and privacy)...**

[image: results]

[image: results continued]

[image: results continued again]

---

***In other words, the final list of elements shows all 9 items, even though only one was selected.***

```
    [
        {'instrument_name': '1290 Infinity LCMS', 
        'instrumentData': '[
                {
                    "sample_name": "SulfaDrugsMix",
                    (...snip...)
                    "instrument_technique": "LiquidChromatography"
                },
                {
                    "sample_name": "SulfaDrugsMix",
                    (...snip...)
                    "instrument_technique": "LiquidChromatography"
                },
                {
                    "sample_name": "SulfaDrugsMix",
                    (...snip...)
                    "instrument_technique": "LiquidChromatography"
                },
                {
                    "sample_name": "SulfaDrugsMix",
                    (...snip...)
                    "instrument_technique": "LiquidChromatography"
                },
                {
                    "sample_name": "SulfaDrugsMix",
                    (...snip...)
                    "instrument_technique": "LiquidChromatography"
                },
                {
                    "sample_name": "SulfaDrugsMix",
                    (...snip...)
                    "instrument_technique": "LiquidChromatography"
                },
                {
                    "sample_name": "SulfaDrugsMix",
                    (...snip...)
                    "instrument_technique": "LiquidChromatography"
                },
                {
                    "sample_name": "Blank",
                    (...snip...)
                    "instrument_technique": "LiquidChromatography"
                },
                {
                    "sample_name": "Blank",
                    (...snip...)
                    "instrument_technique": "LiquidChromatography"
                }
            ]'
        }
    ]
```

***How can I correct this?***

Comment: A bug in st_aggrid. A work around could be to show the main items in the main grid. If an item from main grid is selected, then create another grid call it sub-grid showing the sub-items of the selected grid from the main grid. Now you can select the item in the sub-grid and be able to get the selection.

Comment: Thats a great suggestion - although one of my other posts is about st_aggrid not updating the grid properly when I do exactly that :D The have an update coming out. Maybe the update will fix it :)

Comment: I also think that checking the checkbox in the main grid would allow the sub-items in the nested grid to be returned as normal even if they are not selected. However now there is another list of items in the nested grid that needs to be handled. It would be interesting to see how the author would approach it.